# Yii 2 kartik dialog.prompt with input type textarea

Tags: javascript, yii2, dialog, prompt, kartik-v

I have a button that triggers a kartik dialog.prompt, where text is put in.
I need the input in the dialog to have several rows and line breaking capability (like textarea)

How to change it from a simple text input to textarea?

Here is my javascript:

```
$("#bulk-email-button-invitations").on("click", function() {
    var grid = $("#invitations");
    var keys = grid.yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');

    if (keys.length >= 1){
    krajeeDialog.prompt({label:'Text emailu:', placeholder:'Zadejte text emailu'}, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $(location).attr('href', '/educational-event-invitation/bulk-email?' + $.param({invitations: keys, text: result}));
        } else {
            krajeeDialog.alert('Text emailu nesmí být prázdný!');
        }
    });
    }else{
        krajeeDialog.alert("Nejprve vyberte studenty, kterým chcete poslat email!")
   }
});
```

I found that if type is not defined (unlike label and placeholder in my case), it defaults to "text". But I wasn't able to make the dialog render any type other than a simple one-row text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is not supported in the extension.

### Reason:

The reason is that in the `dialog.js` where the `KrajeeDialog.prototype` is defined the function `bdPrompt` is the one that takes care of the prompt dialog that is to be created and it creates the default field type as `input` rather than deciding on any of the options or parameters passed to `KrajeeDialog.prompt()` although you can pass a  parameter of name `type` like

```
krajeeDialog.prompt({
  label:'Text emailu:', 
  placeholder:'Zadejte text emailu',
  type:'password'
},function(){})
```

but this does not decide if the element will be `input` or `textarea` type, this parameter `type` is passed as the `attribute` of the input element. See the below code block to understand the reason i explained the third line will always create a field of type input.

### File `yii2-dialog/assets/js/dialog.js` Line 110

```
if (typeof input === "object") {
    $inputDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
    $input = $(document.createElement('input'));
    if (input['name'] === undefined) {
        $input.attr('name', 'krajee-dialog-prompt');
    }
    if (input['type'] === undefined) {
        $input.attr('type', 'text');
    }
    if (input['class'] === undefined) {
        $input.addClass('form-control');
    }
    $.each(input, function(key, val) {
        if (key !== 'label') {
            $input.attr(key, val);
        }
    });
    if (input.label !== undefined) {
        msg = '<label for="' + $input.attr('name') + '" class="control-label">' + input.label + '</label>';
    }
    $inputDiv.append($input);
    msg += $inputDiv.html();
    $input.remove();
    $inputDiv.remove();
} else {
    msg = input;
}
```

So you might need to override the javascript function according to your needs if you want to work it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add custom html to krajeeDialog.prompt after all.
In the documentation, kartik-v states:

> content: string|object: If set as a string, it is treated as a raw HTML content that will be directly displayed.

So if I replace the original object in my code with a string containing the desired html, it will render my textarea or any other form element.

For example, replace it with a textarea html:

```
$("#bulk-email-button-invitations").on("click", function() {
    var grid = $("#invitations");
    var keys = grid.yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');

    if (keys.length >= 1){
    krajeeDialog.prompt('<textarea>Sample text...</textarea>', function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $(location).attr('href', '/educational-event-invitation/bulk-email?' + $.param({invitations: keys, text: result}));
        } else {
            krajeeDialog.alert('Text emailu nesmí být prázdný!');
        }
    });
    }else{
        krajeeDialog.alert("Nejprve vyberte studenty, kterým chcete poslat email!")
   }
});
```